# Name of a matrix with one column and row removed

Tags: linear-algebra, teaching, notation

I am looking for the exact name of a matrix where the i-th column and rows have been removed.

I cannot remember how it is called in linear algebra, does anyone got an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See [Math.SE] to ask general questions in mathematics.

Comment: I understand and I will post it on Mathematics!

Comment: I think we mathematicians need to coin a word for "all-but-one" but as an adjective. This is just a thing that comes up everywhere.

Comment: I get the answer on Mathematics, the name that I was looking for was cofactor matrix

Comment: @T.Boutelier No, usually the cofactor matrix is something else: it is a matrix whose entries are all minors (determinants) of a given matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cofactor_matrix for instance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is only called a *submatrix*, but its determinant is known as [*minor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: I am pretty sure that there exists a specific name for this but I cannot remember it!

Comment: Some authors call it a principal submatrix.